# Adding a drawable resource

Tags: android, resources, eclipse-plugin, adt

This must be something I’m just overlooking or possibly my ADT install is out of date.

When I attempt to add a new drawable resource to my project I don’t see a type of Drawable in the “New Android XML file dialog.”

Here’s what I see when adding a resource:

http://img221.imageshack.us/img221/2977/drawable.jpg

What am I missing here?

Comment: Not an answer, but really just write it by hand, you will loose a lot less time.

Comment: So everyone else is manually creating drawable resources? The biggest issue is that Auto complete doesn't work when you manually create an XML file in the drawable directories.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to just be a bug in the plugin. When you first open the dialog the folder is set for "/res/drawable" but once you enter a filename it then complains "One of the types must be selected (e.g. layout, values, etc.)", but "drawable" is not one of the types in the radio box list!

So it's not even possible to put an empty file in the drawable directory (of course with the set of qualifiers that must be given in a set order for pixel density or language, etc).